# OnPropertyChanged not working as expected with ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Here is my model class, the column that I am interested in this question:

```
public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TestImageAspect
    {
        get { return testImageAspect; }
        set
        {
            testImageAspect = value;
            Console.WriteLine("OnPropertyChanged => testImageAspect");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("OperationResult");
        }
    }
    private string testImageAspect;
}
```

`ImageList` is prepared with required images. In the `ObjectListView` I set appropriate column's ImageAspectName to the property name:

[image]

Then on button click I run the following code to change the

```
  Cell c = ...;
  c.TestImageAspect = "success"; // the name exist in ImageList
```

After above code I see that `OnPropertyChanged` has been called, however UI is not updating, unless I hover to the row where it has to change, then I see new icon. I am not looking for dirty workaround, since I know few, but rather want to understand whether ObjectListView has to update UI itself. If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set `UseNotifyPropertyChanged = true`? You could try it with a simple string-property. Maybe its a bug with respect to images and OwnerDraw mode.

Comment: Ah, that was it, brilliant :) It's not so well documented in my opinion.

Comment: Great, I will post an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @Rev1.0, please go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ObjectListView` property `UseNotifyPropertyChanged` has to be set `true`.

[From the official documentation](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html)

> If you set UseNotifyPropertyChanged, then ObjectListView will listen for changes on your model classes, and automatically update the rows when properties on the model classes changed. Obviously, your model objects have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Where you download official documentation from? :)

Comment: You can find the official website her.http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the XAML for the binding - that might help debug this. Also, it's bit confusing that your property is called TestImageAspect but you're passing "OperationResult" to OnPropertyChanged. I'm not sure if OnPropertyChanged would work either. The more usual way would be to do:-

```
public class Cell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string TestImageAspect
    {
        get { return testImageAspect; }
        set
        {
            testImageAspect = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestImageAspect"));
            }

        }
    }
    private string testImageAspect;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what XAML you ask. It's windows forms. "OperationResult" is only in console output, so I am not passing it anywhere. The way you proposed also didn't update UI.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking it was WPF, not WinForms. You're passing "OperationResult" to OnPropertyChanged :- this.OnPropertyChanged("OperationResult");